# For loop python information

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, multiprocessing, pooling

Heres the deal, I have certain entries in my database. I'm calling a django:

```
variables = Variable.objects.order_by('foo').values('foo')
```

Then I have a for statement that executes on each variable found:

```
for x in variables:
   #doing something....
```

My problem is that the "doing something" is an ongoing task... i.e. it doesn't stop. So how would I be able to run a for loop on the second variable?

I believe it has to do with pooling, but doesn't that mean I can only have 4 processes at once? How would I do this if I wanted say 50 separate processes to run for each 50 variables, and each process doesn't stop until a certain time, or ever....

Can this even be done.

Here is my multiprocessing code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
x = Variable.objects.order_by('foo').values('foo')
for t in x:
    t = t.values()
    foo = "".join(t)
    info('Starting...')
    p = Process(target=myfunction, args=(foo,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

myfunction is what runs on an infinite loop...

@samuel:

```
# globals
my_queue = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue() # queue to store our values
stop_event = multiprocessing.Event() # flag which signals processes to stop
my_pool = None

def my_function(foo):
   while not stop_event.is_set():
        print("starting %s" % foo)
        try:
             var = my_queue.get_nowait() # getting value from queue 
        except Queue.Empty:
             print "No more items in queue"
        # do you logic here


# Since `t` could have unlimited size but do wan't to limit processes
# we'll put all `t` value in queue

x = Company.objects.order_by('ticker').values('ticker')
for t in x:
    foo = t.values()
    my_queue.put(foo)

MAX_PROCESSES = len(x)
my_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(MAX_PROCESSES)

for i in range(MAX_PROCESSES):
    my_pool.apply_async(my_function, args=(foo,))
my_pool.close()
my_pool.join()
```

Comment: [`multithreading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)

Comment: I figured it was one of them. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: @MoonCheesez - `threading` is usually a poor choice for 50 concurrent tasks because the python GIL only allows one to run a time. `multiprocessing` would be a better choice. So what was "multithreading" supposed to be?

Comment: You can have any number of workers in a pool. There is no restriction to 4 processes. Whether 50 separate processes are the best choice for your case depend on the size of your computer and what these tasks are. But if they are going to run continuously, 50 concurrent processes may be the only choice even if they thrash.

Comment: so how would I set up multiprocessing for each? I wrote one out but I cannot tell if its going to run concurrently or i waits for the other to be finished. i.e. I'm having trouble around the for-loop...

Comment: I edited my question with my multiprocessing code

Comment: I have to be honest, it seems highly unlikely to me that spawning some number of processes that you expect to run forever is actually going to be the solution to whatever higher level problem you are trying to solve.  It doesn't answer this question, but what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @PaulBecotte I have one script that pulls information from one page every second of the day... I now need to duplicate that for every entry in a certain database table. Over 1k... is that possible?

Comment: My approach would be using celery along with celery beat to schedule recurring tasks (every second).  Maybe a parent job that pulls your list of pages from the database and then triggers a child task with apply_async for each entry.  You certainly don't want something like this running inside a worker or your init process

Comment: @DenisAngell  why do you converting `t` to string?

Comment: ok thanks for the info!! I'll start with celery... Then apply_async! if you have documentation that you think would help me, please feel free to shoot that on over ;)

Comment: randomly chosen blog post, there's plenty... https://realpython.com/blog/python/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/

Comment: @samuel because I'm using that as a variable, which needs to get passed to the function.

Comment: @PaulBecotte Thank you, I really appreciate it the help

Comment: @DenisAngell Well I think `Pool` with `appy_async` shoud do the work here . Let me know if you need examples of using it

Comment: @samuel Yeah I would love an example.

Comment: @DenisAngell Let me know if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

That's the way the solution could be implemented using multiprocessing library.

We'll use `Pool`, `apply_async` and `Queue`

```
# globals
MAX_PROCESSES = 50
my_queue = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue() # queue to store our values
stop_event = multiprocessing.Event() # flag which signals processes to stop
my_pool = None

def my_function(proc_name, var):
   while not stop_event.is_set():
        # do you logic here with var variable


def var_scanner_process():
    # Since `t` could have unlimited size we'll put all `t` value in queue 
    while not stop_event.is_set(): # forever scan `values` for new items
        x = Variable.objects.order_by('foo').values('foo')
        for t in x:
            t = t.values()
            my_queue.put(t)
        time.sleep(10) 

try:
    var_scanner_process = Process(target=var_scanner)
    var_scanner_process.start()
    my_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(MAX_PROCESSES)

    while not stop_event.is_set():
        try: #  if queue isn't empty, get value from queue and create new process
             var = my_queue.get_nowait() # getting value from queue 
             p = Process(target=my_function, args=("process-%d" % i, var))
             p.start()
        exception Queue.Empty:
             print "No more items in queue"

except KeyboardInterrupt as stop_test_exception:
     print(" CTRL+C pressed. Stopping test....")
     stop_event.set()
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help man. Can I get some clarification? First the variables are found, then put  into the "queue", then joined? Then for i in range("50") it applys the async for the function and passes "process id"? what is the process id? and how do I get "t" to "my_function"

Comment: exception Queue.Empty: is an invalid syntax. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @DenisAngell you have to import `Queue` module to handle `Queue.Empty` exception

Comment: @DenisAngell Regarding to your question: All variables found, are put in queue, actually you don't need to use join  as we're just putting variables here. Then we're creating Pool of 50 processes and use appy_async to execute 50 `my_function` processes in parallel. `process id` just for displaying which process is running. All `t` variables are stored in queue and can be accessed from processes by using `my_queue.get_nowait()`

Comment: @DenisAngell remove my_queue.join() and tell me if helped

Comment: I was hoping that the it would run only for the variables stored in the table... If that is 2 then it "pools" 2 processes. Is that what this code is doing? It seems to just run indefinitely..  I have the code that I want to run indefinitely, I just want to spawn a new pool/queue/process for each variable that I return...

Comment: still doesn't exit out

Comment: @DenisAngell Will check the issue with CTRL + C, anyway it not so relevant to your question. You wanted 50 process running forever and checking the queue for new items. is that what you initially wanted?

Comment: I guess I was unclear... I have the process that runs forever already written... I want to run this process for each variable returned from Variable.objects.order_by(... However, because the process that is going to run for each variable doesn't end I need to create separate processes for each variable... Does this make any sense? Find variables, for each variable run x function ( x function/process doesn't end)... So I guess here it would be for each variable add variable and function to queue/pool and run...

Comment: I edited my code to show how I want the MAXPROCESSES & the variable "foo" to work... Can you please tell me if this is correct?

Comment: @DenisAngell I guess I got you :) Your variables are not fixed at start but can be created on the fly, so you want to be able to add new process to the pool for each new var. Right?

Comment: @DenisAngell Modified my answer, now new process will be created each time new item is put to queue

Comment: your code just returns "No more items in queue" Did I do something wrong?

Comment: so I currently only have one variable in the table, so I cant really tell if its running once then going into an infinite loop because no new queues have been added. I actually removed the while statement and it ran one time but after the 10 second timer I got an "IOError: Errno 32 Broken Pipe"

Comment: also, is it cool to just have it looping like that? Will that take up alot of memory?

Comment: @DenisAngell well you can always print `my_queue.get_nowait()` results so you know if your value was fetched. And yes you should loop as you're waiting for a new value to come, an no it doesn't eats your memory :)

Comment: I really appreciate all your help and the fact that you respond back. Thank you very much